# Error in the last dense layer in lstm which is expecting (1,) but given(88,), but for my model I need the last layer to be 88 only

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, lstm, layer

```
def create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, desc_list, photo):
X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
# walk through each description for the image
for desc in desc_list:
    # encode the sequence
    seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([desc])[0]
    # split one sequence into multiple X,y pairs
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        # split into input and output pair
        in_seq, out_seq = seq[:i], seq[i]
        # pad input sequence
        in_seq = pad_sequences([in_seq], maxlen=max_length)[0]
        # encode output sequence
        out_seq = to_categorical([out_seq], num_classes=vocab_size)[0]
        # store
        X1.append(photo)
        X2.append(in_seq)
        y.append(out_seq)
return array(X1), array(X2), array(y)
```

def data_generator(descriptions, photos, tokenizer, max_length):

## loop for ever over images

```
while 1:
    for key, desc_list in descriptions.items():
        # retrieve the photo feature
        photo = photos[key][0]
        in_img, in_seq, out_word = create_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, desc_list, photo)
        yield [[in_img, in_seq], out_word]
```

for i in range(epochs):

```
generator = data_generator(train_descriptions, train_features, tokenizer, max_length)
```

model.fit_generator(generator, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch= steps, verbose=1)
    model.save("models/model_" + str(i) + ".h5")

Error:   ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_20 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (88,)